# Create a list according to another list in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below:

**df1**

```
Sites
['a']       
['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']        
['c']
```

**df2**

```
Site cells
a       2
b       4
c       3
d       5
```

what i need is to add a column in df1 with list of cells corresponding to list in df1
like

**result_df**

```
Sites                   Cells
['a']                   [2]
['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']    [4,3,2,5]   
['c']                   [3]
```

I wrote below, just the column is map object,

```
df1['Cells'] = df1['Sites'].map(lambda x: map(df2.set_index('Site')['cells'],x))
```

I tried using list to convert it to list but I get this error

```
df1['Cells'] = df1['Sites'].map(lambda x: list(map(df2.set_index('Site')['cells'],x)))
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
df1['value'] = df1.Sites.map(lambda x : df2.set_index('Site')['cells'].get(x).tolist())
df1
Out[728]: 
          Sites         value
0           [a]           [2]
1  [b, c, a, d]  [4, 3, 2, 5]
2           [c]           [3]
```

If you have some Sites in df1 not in df2 try with `explode`

```
df1['new'] = df1.Sites.explode().map(df2.set_index('Site')['cells']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: I get error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: @MahdiAbadinia check update

Comment: yes this was problem, and fixed, many thanks